# Communicating between 2 different local subnets

Tags: networking

I have the following equipments & specifications

- 1 Mac OS
- 1 Windows XP
- 1 Linksys Cisco WRT600N router

My Mac OS will be on a local subnet (example 192.168.1.0/24), and my Windows XP will be on another local subnet (example 192.168.2.0/24).

How am I supposed to configure my router in order for both of my 2 subnets (Mac OS & Windows XP) to "talk" to each other ?

On another note, I would also like my MAC OS IP address to be dynamically assigned from the router (DHCP server for this subnet), while my Windows XP IP address can be statically assigned.

Could I get some helps/tips/suggestions here ?

Comment: How are the two subnets going to be connected to each other?

Answer (score 1):

If you were using Linksys routers, you could do this with Static Routing...

> Static Routing
>
> If there are multiple routers on your network, it is necessary to configure the unit's static routing functions. The static routing function determines your network's data paths. Use static routing to allow different IP domain users to access the Internet through your Cable/DSL Router. Click on the Show Routing Table button to view the current routing table.
>
> To create a static route entry:
>
> Select a Static Route Entry from the drop down list. The device supports up to 20 static route entries.
>
> Enter the following data for the static route:
>
> Destination LAN IP : Enter the network address of the remote LAN segment. For a standard Class C IP domain, the network address is the first 3 fields of the Destination LAN IP, while the last field should be 0.
>
> Network Mask : Enter the Subnet Mask used on the destination LAN IP domain. For Class C IP domain, the Subnet Mask is 255.255.255.0.
>
> Gateway IP : If the Linksys router is the main IP router to connect your network to the Internet, then your Gateway IP is the same IP Address as the Linksys router. If you have another router handling your network's Internet connection, enter the IP Address of your main Internet router here instead.
>
> Click the Apply button to save your changes.

This should allow computers in the different subnets to see and communicate with each other.

Comment: As current things stand, I only have one router which I must allow 2 different subnets to communicate with each other using only the router.

Comment: Only one router?  What device is setting the other subnet?  Is it a DSL modem connected directly to a computer, that you are then sharing the internet connection out to the router or network?  With only one router, why the two different subnets?  You said the Windows XP machine would have a static Internal IP, so why not simply set the router on that same subnet, since if the Mac is going to get a dynamic IP, it shouldn't need to be on a different subnet.